# Is C#-4.0 an open standard?

Tags: c#, legal, standards

The Ecma-334 (ISO/IEC 23270:2006) standard corresponds to the version 2.0 of the language.

Specification of version 4.0 is freely available from Microsoft, but Microsoft's [open specifications list](http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/community-promise/covered-specifications/default.aspx) only lists the Ecma (version 2.0) version.

So what about all the good features added in the later versions (LINQ, lambda functions, etc)? Can one implement them in his compiler?

Answer (score 6):

C# 4.0 does not have a published ECMA standard yet.

However, [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) actively adds the [latest C# and .NET Framework features](http://mono-project.com/Roadmap) to its compiler, using the [specifications published by Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)

Comment: But there are agreements between Microsoft and Novell (now Attachmate), and then we don't know about the patents owned by  OIN and CPTN, etc etc... Can you point to the pages/statements that clarify the status for people other than Novell implementing the language, and also the current patenting status of the language?